# Urls на чистом javascript возможно?

Tags: javascript, url

Вопрос в том возможно ли сделать urls на чистом js без express.js, например: books/, books/< id>/, user/< id>/, user/books/ ?

Comment: Что значит "сделать urls"?

Comment: Экспресс написан на чистом JS, так что никто не мешает вам написать свой аналог

Comment: @entithat роутинг, маршрутизация сайта

Comment: @AlexeyTen так для express.js нужно node.js или нет ? Просто я хотел сделать простенький сайт без node.js, вот и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать свой роутинг на клиентской стороне. Но вам всё равно нужен сервер, который примет ваш запрос и отдасть тот же `index.html`. Это помет быть настроеный `Apache` или `Nginx` или любой другой сервер. А может быть сервер написанный на **чистом `js`** исполняемый в `NodeJs`. Любой запрос в написанный в адресной строке броузера передаётся на сервер.

После того как сервер вернул вам ваш `index.html`, в котором подключён скрипт или скрипты которые разберут `урл`. Это и будет ваша маршрутизация. Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос и помог лучше понять технологию.

*P.S. Языку `JavaScript` как и любому другому языку нужет интерпретатор. На стороне клиента интерпретатором выступает броузер, а на сервере `NodeJs`.*